# How to find the probability of extinction = 1 using Galton-Watson process in R?

Tags: r

I am simulating a basic Galton-Watson process (GWP) using a geometric distribution. I'm using this to find the probability of extinction for each generation. My question is, how do I find the generation at which the probability of extinction is equal to 1?

For example, I can create a function for the GWP like so:

```
# Galton-Watson Process for geometric distribution
GWP <- function(n, p) {
  Sn <- c(1, rep(0, n))
  
  for (i in 2:(n + 1)) {
    Sn[i] <- sum(rgeom(Sn[i - 1], p))
  }
  return(Sn)
}
```

where, `n` is the number of generations.

Then, if I set the geometric distribution parameter p = 0.25... then to calculate the probability of extinction for, say, generation 10, I just do this:

```
N <- 10 # Number of elements in the initial population. 
GWn <- replicate(N, GWP(10, 0.25)[10])
probExtinction <- sum(GWn==0)/N 
probExtinction
```

This will give me the probability of extinction for generation 10... to find the probability of extinction for each generation I have to change the index value (to the corresponding generation number) when creating `GWn`... But what I'm trying to do is find at which generation will the probability of extinction = 1.

Any suggestions as to how I might go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell you how you would do this problem *in principle*, but I'm going to suggest that you may run into some difficulties (if you already know everything I'm about to say, just take it as advice to the next reader ...)

- theoretically, the Galton-Watson process extinction probability never goes *exactly* to 1 (unless prob==1, or in the infinite-time limit)
- of course, for any given replicate and random-number seed you *can* compute the first time point (if any) at which all of your lineages have gone extinct. This will be *highly variable* across runs, depending on the random-number seed ...
- the distribution of extinction times is extremely skewed; lineages that don't go extinct immediately will last a loooong time ...

I modified your `GWP` function in two ways to make it more efficient: (1) stop the simulation when the lineage goes extinct; (2) replace the sum of geometric deviates with a single negative binomial deviate (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548525/how-to-compute-the-sum-of-random-variables-of-geometric-distribution))

```r
GWP <- function(n, p) {
  Sn <- c(1, rep(0, n))
  for (i in 2:(n + 1)) {
    Sn[i] <- rnbinom(1, size=Sn[i - 1], prob=p)
    if (Sn[i]==0) break ## extinct, bail out
  }
  return(Sn)
}
```

The basic strategy now is: (1) run the simulations for a while, keep the entire trajectory; (2) compute extinction probability in every generation; (3) find the *first* generation such that `p==1`.

```r
set.seed(101)
N <- 10 # Number of elements in the initial population.
maxgen <- 100
GWn <- replicate(N, GWP(maxgen, 0.5), simplify="array")
probExtinction <- rowSums(GWn==0)/N
which(probExtinction==1)[1]
```

(Subtract 1 from the last result if you want to start indexing from generation 0.) In this case the answer is `NA`, because there's 1/10 lineages that manages to stay alive (and indeed gets very large, so it will probably persist almost forever)

```r
plot(0:maxgen, probExtinction, type="s")    ## plot extinction probability
matplot(1+GWn,type="l",lty=1,col=1,log="y") ## plot lineage sizes (log(1+x) scale)
```

[image: extinction prob vs time]

[image: pop size of lineages vs time]

```r
## demonstration that (sum(rgeom(n,...)) is equiv to rnbinom(1,size=n,...)
nmax <- 70
plot(prop.table(table(replicate(10000, sum(rgeom(10, prob=0.3))))),
     xlim=c(0,nmax))
points(0:nmax,dnbinom(0:nmax, size=10, prob=0.3), col=2,pch=16)
```